# Not receiving callback after ETA calculation from Here Api

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I am trying to calculate ETA between two places using HERE api ,but I am not getting callback from ETA calculation function. Not even getting any  error inside completion handler.

```
let routeMode = NMARoutingMode()
routeMode.transportMode = NMATransportMode.car
routeMode.routingOptions.insert(NMARoutingOption.avoidHighway)
routeMode.routingType = NMARoutingType.fastest
routeMode.resultLimit = 1

var stops = [Any]()

let startPoint = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 52.562755700200796, longitude: 13.34599438123405)

let endPoint = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 52.520720371976495, longitude: 13.332345457747579)

stops.append(startPoint)
stops.append(endPoint)

let coreRouter = NMACoreRouter()
coreRouter.calculateRoute(withStops: stops, routingMode: routeMode) { (routeResult, error) in
/* Not getting callback inside this block. Not even any errors in console */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `coreRouter` is declared locally within a function, which means it will get dismissed as soon as the function finished running. By the time the async method completes, your object has been removed.

**Solution:**

declare `let coreRouter = NMACoreRouter()` at class level and only call the method within the function

**Messy alternative**

wrap your async function `calculateRoute` call inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { /* place here */ }`

Would strongly suggest first option since the second would freeze any other logic until completion is called (but technically it works :) ).